# round robin with limitation _ nodejs

Tags: node.js, algorithm, load-balancing

suppose we have 4 objects that we need to select one of them with conditions.

```
let array_of_objects = [
    {name: "a", weight: 2},
    {name: "b", weight: 4},
    {name: "c", weight: 5},
    {name: "d", weight: 6}
]
```

1. select with weight priority
2. selection has some kind of limits. it means the weight variable has a limit size. for example, if we have an object "d" with a weight of 6 . it cannot be selected.

the goal is to manage tasks between workers. I found round-robin algorithm for this kind of problem. with round-robin you can distribute tasks between nods, workers, servers etc. but the main concept is round-robin can select with one parameter(weight). what if we have multiple parameter that need to be envolved? like (performance , or loads in per nodes)

I also found some package that can use round-robin .
https://www.npmjs.com/package/loadbalance

is there any algorithm can handle this better than round-robin?

Answer (score 1):

As far ask I know, the Weighted Round Robin algorithm would be the best approach. Rightly, as you have said, the standard algorithm takes one "weighting" but in real life multiple parameters are considered. You would have to aggregate those different parameters yourself depending on your priorities to make one overall "weight", perhaps by applying a coefficient to each parameter value depending on its importance. Discarding an object when the weight is too great, should very simple to implement in your solution but I don't know of anything "out-of-the-box".

Comment: tnx for the reply , I used weighted round-robin and it works fine. but this is just for balancing only. I need some sort of solution for managing the threads and workers not just distributing between them.